# R: remove duplicated values in across rows and columns

Tags: r, duplicates

I've found many pages about finding duplicated elements in a list or duplicated rows in a data frame. However, I want to search for duplicated elements throughout the entire data frame. Take this as an example:

```
df
     coupon1    coupon2    coupon3
1         10         11         12
2         13         16         15
3         16         17         18
4         19         20         21
5         22         23         24
6         25         26         27
```

You'll notice that df[2,2] and df[3,1] have the same element (16). When I run

```
duplicated(df)
```

It returns six "FALSE"s because the entire row isn't duplicated, just one element. How can I check for *any* duplicated values within the *entire* data frame? I would like to both know the duplicate exist and also know its value (and the same if there's multiple duplicates).

Comment: is it enough for your purposes to map to a vector: `duplicated(matrix(df, ncol=1))`

Comment: The only thing is this matrix can be thousands of lines long, so I'm looking for a solution that deals with it as a data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find global dupes but it searches columnwise. So (3,1) will still be FALSE as it is the first value `16` in the data frame.

```
m <- matrix(duplicated(unlist(df)), ncol=ncol(df))
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

You can then use it however you'd like, for example:

```
df[m]
#[1] 16
```

Answer (score 1):

```
which(duplicated(stack(yourdf)[,1]))
[1] 8
stack(yourdf)[,1][which(duplicated(stack(yourdf)[,1]))]
[1] 16
```